# Cost of Security updates for Windows Server 2012 R2 after 2018

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I've been searching all over the Support Life Cycle pages at Microsoft.com, but all I can see is that Mainstream Support for Windows Server 2012 R2 ends on 10/9/2018.
So we get no new features. Fine. Not a problem.

But do we still get Security Updates free-of-charge?

Or do we have to have Software Assurance (SA) in order to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will move to extended support for 5 years with just free security updates.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043450/products-reaching-end-of-support-for-2018

> Products Transitioning from Mainstream to Extended Support: The following products will be moving from Mainstream Support into Extended Support over the next year. Extended Support lasts for a minimum of 5 years and **includes security updates at no cost**, and paid non-security updates and support. Additionally, Microsoft will not accept requests for design changes or new features during the Extended Support phase.

This list includes Win Server 2012 and 2012 R2.

Comment: Where do you see the "free security updates"? That is the information that I've been searching high and low for.

Comment: It's clearly written in the header of the extended support section...